# Helium's first excited state (anti-symmetry of the spatial function)

Tags: electrons, symmetry, fermions

[Here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/helium.html#c1), it's explained why, for the first excited state of He, one electron is in 1S orbital and the other electron is in 2S orbital with both spins pointing in the same direction (triplet)

What I am confused about is this:  Since the electrons are in the triplet state (where they are either both pointing up or down), the spin part of the wavefunction is symmetric. Then the spatial part of the function is anti-symmetric.  But if one electron is in 1S and the other is in 2S, how come the composite spatial part is anti-symmetric when they are individually symmetric?

p.s. Is it fair to say for all atoms, the spatial part of the wavefunction is always symmetric for ground state?

Answer (score 1):

The spatial part of the wave function is a so called Slater determinant. It has the form $\psi_{1s}(r_1) \psi_{2s}(r_2)~-~ \psi_{2s}(r_1) \psi_{1s}(r_2)$. So the total wave function is antisymmetric under exchange of the two electrons.